# Populate MultipleChoiceField values from ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm wanting to use my `ManyToManyField` in a form. I read that you should use a `MultipleChoiceField` for this. How can I populate the choices from my `ManyToManyField`?

**models.py**

```
class BoatModel(models.Model): 

    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    model_slug = AutoSlugField(null=True, default=None,
                         unique=True, 
populate_from='title')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Models"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category_slug = AutoSlugField(null=True, default=None, unique=True, populate_from='title')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**forms.py**

```
class CreateModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('title', 'category',)
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'category-title-field', 'placeholder': 'Category title'}),
            'category': forms.MultipleChoiceField(),

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need a ModelMultipleChoiceField, not a MultipleChoiceField. Luckily, for a ModelForm, django will automatically assign a ModelMultipleChoiceField for a ManyToMany, which will by default include all instances of that model as choices.

You should be able to remove "category" from your widgets and it should work fine.

The widget dictionary should be used to display which widget overlay would be used on that ModelMultipleChoiceField, not to call the field itself. You'd only need to call the widget if you want to add any attributes, change the type of input (say, to checkboxes or radio buttons), or to change the queryset. So if you wanted to use a Select and only wanted a subset of categories to show up on the form, you could do the following:

```
class CreateModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('title', 'category',)
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'category-title-field', 'placeholder': 'Category title'}),
            'category': forms.SelectMultiple(queryset=Category.objects.filter(foo=bar),

        }
```